# set up pre-receive hook in server side

Tags: git, bitbucket, hook

I created a **`pre-receive`** hook locally which is in the location .git/hooks of my project directory. I'm using bitbucket as my remote repo. Now how can I bring this pre-receive hook to the remote repo.

because,
`git push` doesn't push the .git directory.
And I cannot create a .git directory in remote repo (bitbucket).

What should I do to set up my pre-receive hook in server side?

Comment: Did you google for bitbuckt server hook? (Just a guess.)

Comment: Yes I did. But I couldn't find these details.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-create-a-simple-hook-in-bitbucket-server-779171711.html

Comment: Looks like you cannot do that with Bitbucket Cloud.. you need Bitbucket Server?? https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/10471/git-server-side-pre-receive-hook-bb-11418

Comment: Looking for same to achieve in Azuredevops server. couldn't find any related information. any guidance?